# Jquery:for loop or $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a doubt about the following scripts which one produce a better performance and how?
Using For Loop:

```
var words=$(".countryList option:selected").text().split(/ +/);
var sum=0;
var limit=14;
var appendWord="";
for(var i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
  sum = sum + words[i].length;
  if(sum <= limit){
    appendWord = appendWord + " " + words[i];
    sum = sum + 1;
  }
}
```

Using $.each() :

```
var words =$(".countryList option:selected").text();
var arr = words.split(/ +/);
var textLimit=13;
var length=0;
var splittedText= '';
$.each(arr,function(i, val){
  length = length + arr[i].length;
  if(length <= textLimit){
    splittedText = splittedText + ' ' + arr[i];
    length = length + 1;
  }
});
```

Here i get the Text from select box and tell to select box to display limited words or characters only..

Answer (score 1):

Yes if we are taking about perfoemance: for loop is much faster than each .
You can verify the same using the console with date funciton that will show the curent date.